# Matrix Multiplication in Python 3

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I am trying to create several functions for Linear Algebra and was completely stuck on matrix multiplication. Below is my working solution, but is there possibly a cleaner solution?

```
def matrix_multiplication(a, b):
     # Transpose matrix b
     bT = list(zip(*b))

     # Multiply the two
     return [[sum([a[ai][j] * bT[bTi][j] for j in range(len(a[ai]))]) for bTi in range(len(bT))] for ai in range(len(a))]
```

Comment: If you have a working solution how are you "completely stuck"? If you simply want to improve working code, [codereview.se] might be a better place to ask (but be sure to first read their posting guidelines and delete this question here if you decide to go that route).

Comment: numpy? And could you add some test data so we don't have to all do that ourselves?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the idiomatic `numpy.matmul` or `@` operator designated for matrix multiplication of NumPy arrays? Perhaps this is a personal learning project?

Comment: As others have said `numpy` is what you should use *if you need to actually perform linear algebra operations*. However, it sounds like you're implementing matrix multiplication for your own edification. For starters, a comprehension this long and messy is objectively bad practice. Run a standard accumulator. Yes, there's a cleaner solution but it follows the same logic, just uses more of Python's powerful syntax, with one exception: you're unnecessarily creating lists in memory instead of summing directly over a generator expression.

Comment: You can try using matmul or dot function depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you all for the insight. If I was actually tasked with finding the product of two matrices I would undoubtedly use numpy, but just for practice I wanted to try it on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstof all, I would only recommend creating a linear algebra library from scratch, if you want to use it for learning purposes. Otherwise you should use numpy.linalg or something similar.

Assuming, you want to do this from scratch, I reccommend to go with object oriented programming approach. This would mean creating your own matrix class.

You can try something similar to this blog: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-a-matrix-module-from-scratch-a4f35ec28b56

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to come up with your own way of computing matrices, it may be that your loop works, but more standard "cleaner" way would be to use "numpy" module.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])
b = np.array([[1,-1,1]])
#Transposing
b = np.transpose(b)
c = np.matmult(A,b)
```